# FFmpeg: How to add shadow overlay at the bottom of the video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay, shadow

I need to add a little shadow at the bottom of the video.

***Initial video***

[image]

***Expected result***

[image]

The one version for doing this is to have the shadow (.png) image which will be added to the video as an overlay. But I thought, is there any way to do it without a shadow image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Using the split, format, geq, and overlay filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -filter_complex "[0]split[v0][v1];[v0]format=rgba,geq=r=0:g=0:b=0:a=255*(Y/H)[fg];[v1][fg]overlay=format=auto" -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 out.jpg
```

- split - make two copies of the input: one for geq and the other for overlay
- format - make the input have alpha channel
- geq - create a gradient with alpha
- overlay - place gradient over original image

---

[image]

Another example but this adds the crop filter to halve the gradient so it stops in the middle:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -filter_complex "[0]split[v0][v1];[v0]crop=iw:ih/2,format=rgba,geq=r=0:g=0:b=0:a=255*(Y/H)[fg];[v1][fg]overlay=0:H-h:format=auto" -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 out.jpg
```

There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but it works. See [filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#geq).

Comment: What would we change if we wanted the overlay at a different position on the video and not the bottom? Could you please elaborate on that bit?

Comment: @NavedKhan Which position?

Comment: For instance, if I wanted the same overlay at the top of the video. ( The overlay would have to be inversed as well )

Comment: I've came up with this solution to add the gradient-angle: https://gist.github.com/coderofsalvation/bb922e8e9cfed101ad4e9e1700d9ef25

Comment: @llogan is it possible to add shadow or shadow image outside(like actual shadow means behind) of the video not an overlay??

Comment: @VivekThummar A drop shadow? You should ask a new question since it would be a completely different method.

Comment: ok, i will ask a new question in next some days(sorry for that)..