# How can I overlay an angled gradient or fade over the corner of a video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, gradient, transparency, lossless

I want to darken the corner of a video with a (for instance) 45-degree black gradient.  I'd like to customize the angle, feathering, color and opacity.  My video is 10-bit UHD HEVC and I need to output to 10-bit lossless intermediate (probably v210 codec).  How can I do all of this in ffmpeg?

Here is a mockup of what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a mockup of what you want to do?

Comment: Okay, I just now added an example image.

Comment: One method is by using the [geq filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#geq). Somewhat similar [FFmpeg: How to add shadow overlay at the bottom of the video?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59380928/).

Comment: The answer provided in your link seems close, but I can't figure out how to adjust the gradient angle.