# How to use ffmpeg to add a drop shadow?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to add a drop shadow to an overlay video using ffmpeg, but haven't had any luck. I was trying using something similar to the command [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368485/ffmpeg-how-to-add-shadow-overlay-at-the-bottom-of-the-video), but I haven't been able to understand it/get it working.

[Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlZiy.jpg)

It's not super easy to tell from my screenshot, but I want a shadow behind the overlay video similar to [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) from css.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Share your closest attempt at a command.

Comment: Try looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72967385/1277576 It is not what you want to achieve, however, you could exploit the same idea of creating a shadow via an image.

Comment: Are you able to find the answer to this?

Comment: I bet this could be reasonably done with a rasterized SVG.  We could make an SVG image with a certain box shadow size in pixels, but placed by percentage.  That way, when the image is rasterized, the feathered edge would be sized correctly no matter the box size.  There's apparently `librsvg` but it isn't enabled in most FFmpeg builds as it has a ton of heavyweight dependencies... so we'd have to build FFmpeg ourselves for this method.  I wonder if this idea sparks any other ideas folks might have.

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i background.mp4 -i overlay.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[1]split[ol][sh]; \
 [sh]geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(p(X,Y))'[sh]; \
 [sh]boxblur=20[sh]; \
 [ol][sh]overlay=10:10[olsh]; \
 [0][olsh]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

The ffmpeg command first splits the overlay video into two streams. One stream undergoes a luminosity-based transparency adjustment `(geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(p(X,Y))')` where brighter pixels become more transparent. This modified stream is then heavily blurred `(boxblur=20)`.  Next, the original overlay and the blurred/transparent version are combined with a 10-pixel offset `([ol][sh]overlay=10:10[olsh])`. Finally, the resulting overlay is centered on top of the background video `([0][olsh]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2")`.

Answer (score 1):

just for fun, gradient background:

```
ffmpeg -lavfi "
color=black:size=1280x720,geq=
 r='lerp(lerp(255,190,X/W),lerp(  0,127,X/W),Y/H)'
:g='lerp(lerp(  0,127,X/W),lerp(  0,255,X/W),Y/H)'
:b='lerp(lerp(127,  0,X/W),lerp(190,255,X/W),Y/H)'
" -frames 1 -y gradient.png
```

1st column (255,0,127) is color left top pixel, 2nd (190,127,0) → right top, 3rd (0,0,190) → left bottom

shadow over the bottom of video:

```
ffmpeg -lavfi "
color=blue:1024x576,format=rgba,geq=lum='p(X,Y)'
:a='if(lt(Y,H*3/4),0,lerp(0,200,sin((Y-H*3/4)/H*PI/2)))'
" -frames 1 -y shadow.png
```

shadow under the video:

```
ffmpeg -i gradient.png -lavfi "
color=orange:1024x576[f];
[0][f]overlay=(W-w)/2+5:(H-h)/2+5,avgblur=10
" -frames 1 -y shadow2.png
```

rounded video, etc:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i shadow.png -i shadow2.png -lavfi "
[0]scale=1024:576,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':
a='if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-20)*gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-20),
if(lte(hypot(20-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),20-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))),20),255,0),
255)'[v];
[1]geq=lum='p(X,Y)':
a='if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-20)*gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-20),
if(lte(hypot(20-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),20-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))),20),alpha(X,Y),0),
alpha(X,Y))'[s];
[2][v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[v];
[v][s]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2
" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  What is `lerp()`?  Is that documented anywhere for `lavfi`?

Comment: lerp(x, y, z) → Return linear interpolation between x and y by amount of z. https://ffmpeg.org//ffmpeg-all.html#Expression-Evaluation